# AMD baseurl and paths ignored

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

This is not a possible duplicated.

Simply put, baseUrl and paths are completely ignored regardless what I do, my configuration file is this one, looks just like that:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: CONTEXTPATH + "/javax.faces.resource/scripts/new",
  paths: {
    "scripts": CONTEXTPATH + "/javax.faces.resource/scripts/new"
  }
})

require([
  "scripts/containers/index.frontpage.js.jsf?",     //it goes to mysite.com/scripts/containers/index.frontpage.js.jsf?
  "scripts/reducers/index.frontpage.js.jsf?"        //it goes to mysite.com/scripts/reducers/index.frontpage.js.jsf?
], function(C, R){
  //some logic....
});
```

And it doesn't matter if I do `/scripts` `./scripts` or `scripts` in the filepaths it will always go to the root, I know the extensions are weird but this is a legacy system, I am running an upgrade and AMD can't even fetch a javascript file, only the absolute path works, but there are modules that can't access CONTEXTPATH, breaking it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the **question mark**. I just tried with my local configuration (which works fine using *baseUrl*). As soon as I change `require(['module'])` to `require(['module?'])` requireJS ignores the baseUrl.

This is strange, however, since according to the [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config), the baseUrl is ignored as soon as (1) the path starts with a slash (`require(['/foo'])`), (2) has a protocol (`require(['http://example.com/foo'])`) or (3) ends with *.js* (`require(['foo.js'])`). The question mark *should* not be a problem (unless it is just forbidden in the naming of modules).

So, just remove the qustion mark. Also, since I do not know what *CONTEXTPATH* looks like, you may as well try using the absolute URL (`http://example.com/...`) (this is how my require config does it and we never had problems).

Also, the `paths` rule defines *exceptions* ("use the baseUrl unless something else is specified in paths").

Comment: Removing the ? causes requirejs to append a .js at the end, and temember that the server only gives `.jsp` files because, well, that's how it was configured 10 years ago.

Comment: I tried also using the noext extension but it doesn't work either, plus it searchs for the extensions using the `.js` ending again, but I could try to define it on site, at the end I made it work writing my own plugin inside the same file.

Comment: ```define("load", function(){
    return {
        load : function(name, req, onLoad, config){
            req([CONTEXTPATH + "/javax.faces.resource/scripts/new/" + req.toUrl(name) + ".js.jsf"], function(mod){
                onLoad(mod);
            });
        },
        normalize : function(name, norm){
            return name;
        }

    };
});

require([
  "load!containers/index.frontpage",
  "load!reducers/index.frontpage"
].....```